# WPF horizonal ListView with multiple rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I'm trying to achieve a horizontal scrollable GridView, similar to what UWP has, but using a ListView in WPF. This is what I'm trying to display:

```
A C E G I ...
B D F H J ...

    <ListView Name="MainGrid"
              Grid.Row="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"\>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you try  ListView.ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"

Comment: But I don't care about the scrollbars. I need to display items horizontally and to actually scroll left and right.

Comment: If you make VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" and WrapPanel  Orientation="Vertical" you can display items horizontally and scroll left and right. Just try....

Comment: Did you conider to use the native UWP control using XAML Islands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want i think..

```
    <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <Button Content="A"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="B"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="C"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="D"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="E"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="F"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="G"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="H"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="I"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
        <Button Content="J"
                Width="100"
                Height="100" />
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I tried this and the bottom cells are partially visible  with any height I would add to the ListView. Also they are not horizontally scrollable when they get off screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView Name="MainGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

> Possible

Comment: It is horizontally scrollable but s single row of items is displayed. I need 2 rows like in my example.